# Making a scalable postgres source machine learning pipeline on GCP

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am currently trying to make a training pipeline on the Google Cloud Platform. While I could train on a single instance, the data can scale <= 1 TB. This leaves me with a few choices as to how to approach the training pipeline of this application with cloud platforms. I am thinking about using a spark connector to Postgres that can read the data and then perform data wrangling using pandas or other dataframe functionality. This would feed into the deep learning/machine learning training and then the model would be output. I have read that something like Airflow/Luigi can help loads with such a pipeline. However, I had a bunch of questions that I would love to know the answer to, before I architect this system:

- When Spark connects to the Postgres database, would it be downloading the entire dataset into temporary files/Avro/Parquet files for processing. Could I use minimum memory here and how would I ensure that this is happening?
- Are there any tools on Google Cloud Platform/AWS that is already capable of something like this? Without stating the reasons, I would not like to use DataBricks.
- I would like to use a plethora of machine learning algorithms. While at the start I would like to use traditional regression methods such as Lasso and such, over time, I would like to start utilizing more deep learning techniques such as CNNs/RNNs. I know this is a laden question, and is maybe suitable to its own Stack Overflow question.
- Are there any scalability issues to this architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to this was using something along the lines of:

[image]

Please let me know if there is any feedback about this architecture.